# My 3 divs aren't lining up properly. Right most div is being pushed down by undefined margin?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 3 divs inside a wrapper div.  Inside my wrapper div, my leftmost div is an arrow image I'm using to navigate between sliders using js.  The middle div is the slider, and the right div is the right arrow to move to the next slider.

Here's the code for the slider:

```
<div class="twocol_double">
    <div class="btn_left"></div>
    <div id="slide_wrapper">
        <div class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 3; opacity: 1;">

            <h3>Heading1</h3>

            <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vol</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn_right"></div>
</div>
```

There will be multiple `slide` classes, but for the sake of the question I only added 1.

For some reason though, my right div with my right arrow is being pushed down. Looking at it in Chromes element inspector there is a 50px right margin on my slider div that I'm not defining anywhere (I see the orange color, but there's no CSS markup for it).

I've recreated the problem in jsfildde here:  http://jsfiddle.net/maZbF/1/

I want that right arrow to line up with the other two divs.  I've wrecked my brain trying to figure this out and debug it in chrome with no avail.  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is that your right div is `position:relative` while the left is `position:absolute`. I think you can simplify this layout using simple floats though:

HTML

```
    <div class="twocol_double">
    <div class="btn_left"></div>
    <div id="slide_wrapper">
        <div class="slide">
            <h3>Heading1</h3>
            <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vol</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn_right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.twocol_double {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.btn_left {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 170px;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc url("http://i.imgur.com/7bYsZJD.gif") no-repeat center center;
}
#slide_wrapper {
    width: 460px;
    height: 131px;
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
.btn_right {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
    height: 170px;
    float: right;
    background: #ccc url("http://i.imgur.com/0QRkQ2M.gif") no-repeat center center;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #7DAC20;
}
p, blockquote {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #636B75;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Eb3TA/

Comment: Your code works, but the `position` has nothing to do with why the right button was ending up where it was. :)

Comment: Worked! I was over analyzing again.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In order for floated content to stay on the same line, *all* floated content has to be defined before any normal content.

In this case, you have your left button floated to the left first, which works because it was first. Then you have your division which is not floated and is `display: block`. A block-level element will always push anything after it down to the next line, even if you define a width for it. So when it gets to your right button after that, it is starting on a new line and floating to the right of that new line. It's starting 131px down from the top, since your division before that has a `height: 131px` defined on it (and the other content inside it is just overflowing past the boundaries, not interfering with your right-floated element).

So, you have a couple options:

1. Define your right button immediately after the left button.
2. Float all three elements to the left so they stack on top of each other.

Comment: Ahh I didn't see this under after I accepted the answer.  I think I see the problem.  Thank you for explaining!

Comment: The first line is very important and helpful. Did not know it. thanks.